# Rendering Multiple Animated Components in React Native Only Triggers Once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

So I have created a custom animated component `AnimatedLabel` that just wraps a `Text` in react-native. The component works fine, but it only plays once as in the case below.

Here is the code for `AnimatedLabel`

```
import React, {useRef, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Animated} from 'react-native';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

const Label = styled.Text`
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Inter-Regular';
  color: #3a3a3a;
  opacity: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
`;
const MainLabel = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(Label);
export const AnimatedLabel = props => {
  const [animatedValue] = useState(new Animated.Value(0));
  const opacityValue = useRef(animatedValue).current; // Initial value for opacity: 0

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(opacityValue, {
      toValue: 0.99,
      duration: 1500,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();

    // reverse the animation on unmount
    return () => {
      Animated.timing(opacityValue, {
        toValue: 0.01,
        duration: 1000,
        useNativeDriver: true,
      }).start();
    };
  }, [opacityValue]);

  return (
    <MainLabel style={{opacity: opacityValue}}>{props.children}</MainLabel>
  );
};
```

And here is where I try to use it in a multistep form.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';
import {AnimatedLabel} from '../../../components/animated/labels';
import {AnimatedView} from '../../../components/animated/views';
import Button, {ButtonTypes} from '../../../components/buttons';
import {DefaultInput} from '../../../components/inputs/index';

const Container = styled.SafeAreaView`
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: white;
`;

export default function NewAccount() {
  const [step, setStep] = useState(0);

  const handleNext = () => {
    if (step < 10) {
      setStep(step + 1);
    }
  };

  const handleBack = () => {
    if (step === 0) {
      setStep(0);
    }
    setStep(step - 1);
  };

  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return (
        <Container>
          <AnimatedLabel>Welcome, What's Your Name?</AnimatedLabel>
          <AnimatedView>
            <DefaultInput placeholder="Name" />
            <Button onPress={() => handleNext()}>Next</Button>
          </AnimatedView>
        </Container>
      );
    case 1:
      return (
        <Container>
          <AnimatedLabel>What's Your Email?</AnimatedLabel>
          <AnimatedView>
            <DefaultInput placeholder="Email" />
            <Button type={ButtonTypes.LINK} onPress={() => handleBack()}>
              Back
            </Button>
            <Button onPress={() => handleNext()}>Next</Button>
          </AnimatedView>
        </Container>
      );
    case 2:
      return (
        <Container>
          <AnimatedLabel>What's Your Password?</AnimatedLabel>
          <AnimatedView>
            <DefaultInput placeholder="Password" />
            <Button type={ButtonTypes.LINK} onPress={() => handleBack()}>
              Back
            </Button>
            <Button onPress={() => handleNext()}>Next</Button>
          </AnimatedView>
        </Container>
      );
    case 3:
      return (
        <Container>
          <AnimatedLabel>Confirm Your Password?</AnimatedLabel>
          <AnimatedView>
            <Button type={ButtonTypes.LINK} onPress={() => handleBack()}>
              Back
            </Button>
            <Button onPress={() => handleNext()}>Next</Button>
          </AnimatedView>
        </Container>
      );
    case 4:
      return (
        <Container>
          <AnimatedLabel>What's Your Phone Number?</AnimatedLabel>
          <AnimatedView>
            <Button type={ButtonTypes.LINK} onPress={() => handleBack()}>
              Back
            </Button>
            <Button onPress={() => handleNext()}>Next</Button>
          </AnimatedView>
        </Container>
      );
    case 5:
      return (
        <Container>
          <AnimatedLabel>What's Your Address?</AnimatedLabel>
          <AnimatedView>
            <Button type={ButtonTypes.LINK} onPress={() => handleBack()}>
              Back
            </Button>
            <Button onPress={() => handleNext()}>Next</Button>
          </AnimatedView>
        </Container>
      );
    case 6:
      return (
        <Container>
          <AnimatedLabel>What's Your City?</AnimatedLabel>
          <AnimatedView>
            <Button type={ButtonTypes.LINK} onPress={() => handleBack()}>
              Back
            </Button>
            <Button onPress={() => handleNext()}>Next</Button>
          </AnimatedView>
        </Container>
      );
    case 7:
      return (
        <Container>
          <AnimatedLabel>What's Your State?</AnimatedLabel>
          <AnimatedView>
            <Button type={ButtonTypes.LINK} onPress={() => handleBack()}>
              Back
            </Button>
            <Button onPress={() => handleNext()}>Next</Button>
          </AnimatedView>
        </Container>
      );
    case 8:
      return (
        <Container>
          <AnimatedLabel>What's Your Zip Code?</AnimatedLabel>
          <AnimatedView>
            <Button type={ButtonTypes.LINK} onPress={() => handleBack()}>
              Back
            </Button>
            <Button onPress={() => handleNext()}>Next</Button>
          </AnimatedView>
        </Container>
      );
    case 9:
      return (
        <Container>
          <AnimatedLabel>What's Your Country?</AnimatedLabel>
          <AnimatedView>
            <DefaultInput placeholder="Country" />
            <Button type={ButtonTypes.LINK} onPress={() => handleBack()}>
              Back
            </Button>
            <Button onPress={() => handleNext()}>Next</Button>
          </AnimatedView>
        </Container>
      );
    case 10:
      return (
        <Container>
          <AnimatedLabel>What's Your Date of Birth?</AnimatedLabel>
          <AnimatedView>
            <Button type={ButtonTypes.LINK} onPress={() => handleBack()}>
              Back
            </Button>
            <Button onPress={() => handleNext()}>Next</Button>
          </AnimatedView>
        </Container>
      );
    default:
      return (
        <Container>
          <AnimatedLabel>Welcome , What's Your Name?</AnimatedLabel>
        </Container>
      );
  }
}
```

The animation only works on step 0. For other steps, it just appears as nothing happened. No animation whatsoever. I also noticed that the component doesn't fade out when unmounting.

Is there a way to fix this?

I've tried implementing this in other ways but still no headway.